# How to run protractor using browserify?

Tags: angularjs, cucumber, protractor, browserify

Can anyone tell me how to run protractor using browserify? I have prepared bundle.js file. But I don't know how to execute command **'protractor protractor-config.js'** in browser console. It is undefined in browser console.

Comment: Any news on this topic? I'd like to do the same but with webpack.

Comment: Hi, no updates. I am not working on this anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you aren't going to be able to do this. Protractor is [a Node.js application](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/protractor-setup#prerequisites), to say nothing of its requirement for Selenium. It uses Node to execute, not the browser.